# How to add a comment / description in nexus repository

Tags: java, maven, nexus

We are using nexus to store our jar files (built using maven build). Currently there is a requirement to store a comment alongside our jar

It is sufficient to add this **comment** to the summary section or as another column alongside repository path.

[image]

The comment should be ideally read as a tag from the pom file.

Please provide suggestions on how this can be done. Is there any plugins already available to do this?

Comment: If you buy the commercial version of Nexus there you can add meta data t othe artifacts. But from my point of view it does not make sense to add comment cause for which purpose and which kind of benfit you have from them cause everything is in the pom you need.

Answer (score 0):

Attached a screen shot of advanced search section of Nexus GUI. Using this screen, your customers can make searches.
[image]

- Provide full project information in individual poms. These are : "name,    description, url, inceptionYear, licenses, organization, developers, contributers"
- The project information taken from poms will be displayed extensively in "site documentation" which you will be generating using `maven site`. But in Nexus GUI only basic information will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you Ozgen . Is there a way to view the site details via nexus. since our clients need these information before downloading the jar

Comment: Attached a screen shot of advanced search section of Nexus GUI. Using this screen, your customers can make a search.